# xubuntu install from cd on an old laptop

Tags: system-requirements

I have found my old Compaq Armada E500 laptop and I thought Xubuntu would run fine on it. I burned a CD with Xubuntu 12.10 32bit and loaded it up, but all I could hear is the constant seeking of the CD head, I couldn't even reach the language selector menu.

I tried burning the CD 3 times, even on RW media. I tried to defragment the ISO before burning it to CD but none of them helped. This is not the first time I encountered this problem with a different laptop (but that was old as well), I thought back then that the CD was poorly written.

Windows XP install, Debian or GParted CD loads fine (so the DVD ROM should be OK) on this E500, and the Xubuntu install CD load fine as well on a Lenovo X230 and does not seek a lot.

Is it possible that I need to write the CD with different settings so that it works well in an older (9-10 years old) DVD-ROM? I burned the CD with 16x speed, with Infrarecorder (in Windows 7).

Comment: This question was asked at 6th of January, 2013. The question at your link was asked at 17th of August, 2013. Only through some strange time loop could this be a duplication of that question.

Comment: @karatedog Generally speaking, it does not matter when the question was asked. We tend to close as a duplicate of the older one, but if the newer one gained a better answer before being duped, we might as well do it the other way around.

Comment: @FEichinger: I understand, I have just spent some time here and I have always met with "This question has been asked *before*", and I was just nitpicking on "*before*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compaq Armada E500 laptops had [128Mb of RAM](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/compaq-armada-e500-15/4505-3121_7-30003409.html), Xubuntu requires [256 Mb of RAM](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) to install and 512Mb is strongly recommended to run it. Although you may try the alternative installer which only requires 64Mb.